# pythonocc loading .3md format

Tags: python, cad, opencascade

In the pythonOCC examples CADViewerMDI.py the CAD format step, stp, iges, igs, and brep are suported.

Do pythonOCC support the format ".3dm" and if, how do I load it.

Supoptimal sulution:
Change the format in rhino to one of the other formats.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pythonOCC do not currently support .3dm files you can either output from Rhino in another format, (sub-optimal in your post), or find/write/sponsor the writing of a .3dm importer for pythonOCC.